# my SQL SELECT Columns From Multiple Tables Without Repeating Data

Tags: mysql

```
create table Student (
St_ID int not null,
St_Name varchar (100),
St_tel int,
St_ADD varchar (100) not null,
St_city varchar (100)not null,
St_type varchar (20) not null,
St_nationality varchar (20) not null,
Dep_ID int,
C_ID int,
primary key (St_ID),
foreign key (Dep_ID) references Department(Dep_ID),
foreign key (C_ID) references Course(C_ID),

)

create table Course (
C_ID int not null,
C_Name varchar (30) not null,
C_Duration varchar (10) not null,
DegreeType varchar (20),
Dep_ID int,
primary key (C_ID),
foreign key (Dep_ID) references Department (Dep_ID),
)


insert into Course Values (4040,'Software Engineering','18months','HND',001)
insert into Course Values (1454,'Business IT','6months','Diploma',001)
insert into Course Values (1534,'Business management ','18months','HND',002)
insert into Course Values (1245,'Digital Media','6months','Diploma',001)
insert into Course Values (1243,'Business Development','10months','Diploma',001)

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1212,'jerome jacobs',0774750407,'no 66/7 senananyake lane ','nawala','fulltime','HND','SL',001,4040);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1713,'john paul',0773435646,'no 77/9 alvatigala  lane','colombo ','parttime','Diploma','SL',001,1454);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1614,'Angelo mathews',0773436777,'no 88 rose lane colombo ','colombo 2','fulltime','HND','SL',002,1534);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1514,'jean paul',0713556688,'no 100/1 4th lane nawala','nawala','fulltime','Diploma','SL',002,1245);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1316,'Mark francis',0755657665,'no 54 1st lane ','kotte','parttime','HND','SL',003,4040);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1117,'Kevin steffan',0757667687,'no 99/5 railway lane ','nugegoda','parttime','Diploma','SL',004,1243);

SELECT DISTINCT  Student.St_ID,St_Name,St_tel,St_ADD,St_type,DegreeType,C_Name  from Student,Course where Student.St_type='parttime' and Course.DegreeType='HND';
```

this is my query to get information from two tables but it repeat values how can i fix that im really curious about sql im a beginner sorry for the way i ask questions i will be reall great full if it is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `JOIN` the tables using the common field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.St_ID,St_Name,St_tel,St_ADD,St_type,DegreeType,C_Name  
from Student JOIN 
     Course ON Student.C_ID =Course.C_ID 
where Student.St_type='parttime' and Course.DegreeType='HND';
```

An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them.

Read more about joins [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the `student` and  `course` tables together by specifying their common column (key). Instead of this:

```
from Student,Course
```

do this:

```
from Student
join Course on student.C_ID= Course.C_ID
```

If you don't connect the two tables properly you'll get the cartesian product set.

Answer (score 0):

Click  for Information [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT S.St_ID, St_Name, St_tel, St_ADD, St_type, DegreeType, C_Name
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Course C ON S.C_ID = C.C_ID
WHERE S.St_type='parttime' and C.DegreeType='HND'
GROUP BY S.St_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MySql Join , if you need to understand it more : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html